# BeforeStoreRemove is not firing when I remove account from outlook via Contextmenu

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am trying to capture Store Removing using **BeforeStoreRemove** event from Stores. But It is not firing.
I have define `private Outlook.NameSpace outlookns = null;` on top level and `outlookns = this.Application.GetNamespace("mapi"); outlookns.Stores.BeforeStoreRemove += StoreBeforeStoreRemove;`adding in Statup method of **ThisAddIn** Class. I want to capture store in side  `private void StoreBeforeStoreRemove(Outlook.Store store, ref bool cancel) { //want to manupulate here store item }`
But unfortunately it is not firing and hiting my code **StoreBeforeStoreRemove** method when I delete outlook account using Contextmenu from outlook.[image]
it will be great if someone help me for this issue.

Update:
I am using office 365 as following version [image]

Complete code here

```
namespace OutookTestPlugin
{
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    Outlook.Stores Stores = null;
    Outlook.NameSpace outlookns = null;
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        outlookns = this.Application.GetNamespace("mapi");
        Stores = outlookns.Stores;
        Stores.BeforeStoreRemove += StoreBeforeStoreRemove;
    }

    private void StoreBeforeStoreRemove(Outlook.Store Store, ref bool 
  Cancel)
    {
       //handle store need to delete
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Note: Outlook no longer raises this event. If you have code that 
        //    must run when Outlook shuts down, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=506785
    }

    #region VSTO generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }
    
    #endregion
}
```

}
Result from outlookSpy
[image]
Thanks
Shyam Shah

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common .Net problem - the object firing events must be kept alive - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23809877/332059

In your case, `outlookns.Stores` must be stored in a dedicated class member, and event handler must be set on that variable.

Comment: I have use try defining Outlook.Stores gloablly

Comment: No does it work if `Namespace.Stores` is stored in a dedicated variable?

Comment: I have not get chance to test it today and I will update you tomorrow

Comment: I have tested and it is not trigger BeforeStoreRemove  event

Comment: Do you see that event (as well as StoreAdd) fire in OutlookSpy (https://www.dimastr.com/outspy, I am its author)? Click Namespace button on teh OUtlookSpy ribbon, select Stores property, click Browse. In the Stores window, go to the Events tab. Does the event fire (in the log at the bottom of the window) when you remove the store in Outlook?

Comment: I have updated screenshot from OutlookSpy @Dmitry

Comment: Does this only happen with a particular store kind? In my environment, I can see two events firing when I remove a test PST store from the profile:

`BeforeStoreRemove (IDispatch, false)` and `<Unknown(DispID=0x0000F003)> ()`

Comment: Also, do you see `StoreRemove` event firing in Redemption? Try to run the following script from OutlookSpy: when RDOStores window pops up, check the events on the Events tab

`set rSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")`
`rSession.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT`
`set rStores = rSession.Stores`
`BrowseObject(rStores)`

Comment: I am not using any third party tool so, I can not use. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Since you consistently see an event with dispid of 0xF003 firing (looks like it is `StoreRemove` event that fires after the fact and hence does not pass `Store` object as its argument), you can dynamically subscribe to that COM event, even if it is not for the fainthearted, and or simply fire a timer and check the Stores collection every once in a while to see if any stores are gone.

Answer (score 0):

By using the following line code:

```
outlookns.Stores.BeforeStoreRemove
```

The `Stores` property returns an instance of the [Stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.stores) object which represents a set of `Store` objects representing all the stores available in the current profile. But unlike .Net collections this is a COM class which is released as soon as the scope ends. What you really need to do is to define the `Stores` instance at the class level like you did with a namespace object:

```
private Outlook.NameSpace outlookns = null;
private Outlook.Stores stores = null;

...

outlookns = this.Application.GetNamespace("mapi");
stores = outlookns.Stores;
stores.BeforeStoreRemove += StoreBeforeStoreRemove;
```

Defining object at the class level you can be sure the COM objects will be alive and you get the events fired correctly.

Comment: Not working. I mean it is not trigger BeforeStoreRemove event

Comment: I had tried before posting question here and it was not working.

Comment: I have just tested your scenario in my Outlook with the same version numbers. The event is fired correctly when the store is closed (removed). Try to add a separate store in Outlook and then close it, not an account.

Comment: I will create separe project and test it . Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer.